# What is the best way to publish a REST API so that other people can see and improve/add new methods on it?

Tags: design, python, api, api-design

I have a requirement to (re)design an existing REST API which is written in Django REST. One of the main requirements is allowing third parties, approved by us, extending of our API. The API is a gateway to couple systems like central ldap, application databases, mail configuration etc. and provides couple means of authentication and authorization but should be extended per third parties specific requirements that get consulted with us.

My initial solution was posting whole API on git and allowing pull requests that will get merged or not, but I am not sure if this is an optimal solution. How one goes about designing an easily extensible REST API in python?

Comment: You are asking how to make a REST that will be extended by others? Or how is the best way to publish a REST so other people can see and improve/add new methods on it?

Comment: @OscarPichi I'm struggling with both but the main question is the latter. How to publish REST API so that people from other branches of my organisation can easily epxand it to suit their needs with as little as possible overhead from the team maintaining the API.

Answer (score 3):

If you indeed want other developers to work on the actual code, then yes, source control is the solution. If you want control over what goes in, then indeed PR's seem like the correct choice.

If you use GitHub you can provide comments before merging a PR